# Implementing H3-JS in Mapbox based map to Openlayers based map

Tags: openlayers, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, h3

In the H3-JS example I have, it is implemented in mapbox. But I would like to integrate the H3-JS binning as part of Openlayers map instead.
This is the example I want to implement in OpenLayers. https://github.com/agrc/gis.utah.gov/tree/master/developer/applications/suitability

I had asked this question at the Mapbox Github repo, and was told it can be done.
https://github.com/uber/h3-js/issues/160#issuecomment-1251248799

```
function renderHexes(map, hexagons) {
      console.log("renderHexes");

      // Transform the current hexagon map into a GeoJSON object
      // const geojson = geojson2h3.h3SetToFeatureCollection(
        binnedGeoJSON = geojson2h3.h3SetToFeatureCollection(
        Object.keys(hexagons),
        (hex) => ({ value: hexagons[hex] })
      );

      const sourceId = "h3-hexes";
      const layerId = `${sourceId}-layer`;
      let source = map.getSource(sourceId);

      // Add the source and layer if we haven't created them yet
      if (!source) {
        map.addSource(sourceId, {
          type: "geojson",
          data: binnedGeoJSON, //geojson,
        });
        map.addLayer({
          id: layerId,
          source: sourceId,
          type: "fill",
          interactive: false,
          paint: {
            "fill-outline-color": "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
          },
        });
        source = map.getSource(sourceId);           
      }

      // Update the geojson data
      source.setData(binnedGeoJSON); //geojson);
      //Call my new function to carry out H3-JS in Openlayers
      newMap(binnedGeoJSON);
      console.log('end tomap2')

      // Update the layer paint properties, using the current config values
      map.setPaintProperty(layerId, "fill-color", {
        property: "value",
        stops: [
          [0, config.colorScale[0]],
          [0.5, config.colorScale[1]],
          [1, config.colorScale[2]],
        ],
      });

      map.setPaintProperty(layerId, "fill-opacity", config.fillOpacity);
    }
```

And my new function is

```
function newMap(geoJSON)
{
    console.log('Begin NewMap Function: ');
    var coord = [-76.95266723632812, 39.07974903895123];
    
    var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geoJSON, { //geojsonObject
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
    });

    var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({ features: features });
    var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource,
            style: function (feature, resolution) {
                console.log(feature.getProperties(), feature.get('marker-color'));
                return [new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                    radius: 10,
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: feature.get('marker-color') })
                })
                })];
        }
    });

    var map3 = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map3',
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM() }),
                vectorLayer
            ],
            view: new ol.View({
                center: ol.proj.fromLonLat(coord),
                zoom: 5
            })
    });
    // Add the created layer to the Map
    //map3.addLayer(vectorLayer);
    console.log('End NewMap Function: ');
}
```

But still the H3-binning results are now shown in the OpenLayers map. Maybe I have to find the Openlayers equivalent for the following function.

**So my main question is how to convert the below code block in Mapbox into Openlayers?**

```
// Update the layer paint properties, using the current config values
  map.setPaintProperty(layerId, "fill-color", {
    property: "value",
    stops: [
      [0, config.colorScale[0]],
      [0.5, config.colorScale[1]],
      [1, config.colorScale[2]],
    ],
  });
```

Upon commenting out the style function, as suggested by Mike, I only get the frames pf the hexagons. They are not shaded and also binning needs to be carried out.

Please advice.

[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: If you comment out the style function do you see hexagons in the OpenLayers default style?  If not you may need to specify `dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',` in addition to `featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'`.  How does `marker-color` relate to your original code?  To style a polygon with an image with you would to set the style geometry to its interior point.  For `fill-color` your style function could set different fill colors depending on a feature property value.

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you. Commenting out the style shows the hexagons in Openlayers. But only shows frames of the hexagons - they are not shaded inside. I now also have to code it so that the hexagons get smaller or bigger based on the binning parameters. Are you able for chat?

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to style the features according to a property `"value"` as the the Mapbox code you should create corresponding OpenLayers fill styles from your `colorScale` array

```
var outlineColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)';
var styles = config.colorScale.map(function(fillColor) {
  return new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: outlineColor,
      width: 1,
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: fillColor,
    }),
  });
});
```

then you can use a style function to return the appropriate style

```
style: function (feature, resolution) {
  var value = feature.get('value');
  return styles[value < 0.5 ? 0 : value < 1 ? 1 : 2];
}),
```

If you have two sets of data from h3 (`geojson` and `binnedGeoJSON`?) it will probably be easier to use a separate OpenLayers source and layer for each.

**UPDATE**

Your Mapbox code is interpolating colors instead of using simple stops, which will make the OpenLayers style function more involved, as it will need to calculate interpolated colors:

```
function interpolateColor(value, stops, colors) {
  const index = stops.findIndex((stop) => value <= stop);
  if (index < 0) {
    return colors[colors.length - 1];
  }
  if (index === 0) {
    return colors[0];
  }
  const startColor = ol.color.asArray(colors[index - 1]);
  const endColor = ol.color.asArray(colors[index]);
  const startStop = stops[index - 1];
  const endStop = stops[index];
  const result = [0, 0, 0, 0]
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    result[i] = startColor[i] + ((endColor[i] - startColor[i]) * (value - startStop) / (endStop - startStop))
  }
  return ol.color.asString(result);
}

var outlineColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)';
var style = new ol.style.Style({
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: outlineColor,
    width: 1,
  }),
  fill: new ol.style.Fill(),
});
```

and set that in the returned style

```
style: function (feature, resolution) {
  var value = feature.get('value');
  style.getFill().setColor(interpolateColor(value, [0, 0.5, 1], config.colorScale))
  return style;
}),
```

Working example https://jsbin.com/nosoyonemi/edit?html,output (without your school and bus stop local data)

Comment: Hi Mike, this is not working. the map is not showing now. I know you know what you are doing. Thus, I was wondering if you can modify the original example using mapbox, so that it uses openlayers. If that works then it would be easier for me.
https://github.com/agrc/gis.utah.gov/blob/master/developer/applications/suitability/index.html

Comment: I have update the answer

Comment: Thanks it works. I dont have enough reputation to mark this as the answer but this is the answer.

Comment: Dear  Mike, 
You have answered the main question.
I was just wondering how to implement the Buffer Radius option where users can choose the radius. Please see example here - but its in mapbox map. I was wondering how to do that in Openlayers, especially in the jsbin example you have created.
https://observablehq.com/@nrabinowitz/h3-tutorial-using-point-layers?collection=@nrabinowitz/h3-tutorial 
I can post this as a separate question here.

Comment: On that page, on the right, three dots, there is an option to Export and Download Code.

Comment: Okay, posted that as a separate question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/442982/h3-js-binning-buffer-radius-option-in-openlayers-instead-of-mapbox

Comment: Hi @Mike, the solution works, but I have to customize it for a webpage where the openlayers map should only display where the user clicks a button and then when the  the slider is changed for binning, the map should refresh. This works for mapbox, but it doesn't work for openlayers. Somehow the map.once("rendercomplete", async () => function is not being called and the eventlistener is not assigned. I try to call the init() function after the button click, but its inside the module as well as all other functions. I have been trying for days but its not working.

Comment: Updated question with screenshot of the our webpage and when it should display the map.